# NLog Live Viewing/Monitoring

Tags: c#, nlog

I am using NLog as my logging framework. I envisage I will have logs coming in from multiple sources (20, 30+)

I want to be able to live monitor at will.

What Viewers (commercial or free) are the best to use?

I am currently rolling over my days and using C:\Logging as my "base" logging directory.

NLog FileName for trace is as follows:

```
C:\Logging\${appdomain:format={1\}}\${shortdate}\MyType.xml
```

I have Trace/Debug/Info,Warn/Error/Fatal all going into their own separate files (Debug.xml/Info.xml/Error.xml etc), all in the above file name format.

I also have a UDP target setup, and that is currently going to Sentinel. This works fine, and would be a great solution for me if sentinel could setup multiple apps/tabs/receiveds. But on the surface, I can only have one it would seem. The other problem is that I have millions of logs pumping through. Last time i left it running for a while, it killed all the memory in my system.

Ideally, What i would like, is an application that i simply add the "C:\Logging" folder to, like a "watch folder" and it keeps pumping out my logs, including detecting when a new file is created (example Fatal.xml), which would also handle date rollovers. Also the addition of multiple receiver types eg UDP

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if Amazon is an option for you, but I ran across an [AWS NLog Target](https://github.com/aws/aws-logging-dotnet) that I was looking implement.  I am not capturing as many logs as you, but do have logs coming from multiple servers. This would send the items written to the logs to Amazon CloudWatch Logs target and searchable in the console.

I am not sure on the bandwidth required to duplicate log items to AWS but it would put them in one place.  CloudWatch Retention has been increased but if you do find issues, you could always go back to the text log files for more details past the retention period.

You could also setup CloudWatch Alarms to let you know if there are issues.